# I am trying to create a subquery within the SELECT clause

Tags: sql, select

```
SELECT 
    emp_no, last_name, first_name, 
    (SELECT emp_no
     FROM dept_emp de
     WHERE dept_no IN (SELECT dept_no
                       FROM departments d
                       WHERE e.emp_no = de.emp_no))
FROM employees e;
```

[ERD diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14KFZ.png)

List all employees in the Sales department, including their employee number,
last name, first name, and department name.

```
SELECT e.emp_no, last_name, first_name, dept_name
FROM employees e
JOIN dept_emp de ON e.emp_no = de.emp_no
JOIN departments d ON de.dept_no = d.dept_no
WHERE d.dept_name = 'Sales';
```

Basically looking for alternative advanced methods to do this `SELECT`, the more complex the better.

Comment: What does "alternative advanced methods" mean?  Since when is "the more complex the better"?  I don't understand what you are asking and complexity and advanced seem like opinions.

Answer (score 0):

A more complex subquery you can try is to use a CTE (Common Table Expression).

An example might be:

```
WITH employee_salary AS (
SELECT
    employee.emp_no, 
    employee.last_name,
    employee.first_name, 
    salary.salary
FROM employee
JOIN salary
    ON salary.emp_no = employee.emp_no
)

WITH employee_over_30 AS (
SELECT
    emp_no,
    last_name,
    first_name
FROM employee
WHERE employee.age > 30
)

SELECT emp_no, last_name, first_name, department, avg_emp_salary
FROM employee_salary d join
    employees_over_30 o
WHERE d.emp_no = s.emp_no
```

You can also try SQL views and include them in queries as well.